# Reach Forgot Password programatically with MSAL-React

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, msal-react

I have a working b2c/msal setup, I do not use the popup, but instead use the aquireTokenSilent method.

I wanted to create a reset password button/link on my website, that a user can click and be sent into the b2c password reset flow. Ideally, i can add a page with the internal reset password and send an email with that link to people

I thought i can call loginRedirect with the b2c password reset authority, but it just errors out with AADB2C90037.

is there a way we can programatically go directly into the forgot password/reset password from a custom link on a website/email

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom policies?

If so, that error "AADB2C90037: An error occurred while processing the request" means that you have to check the error with [AppInsights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).